# How to trigger chef-client on all nodes from my workstation

Tags: azure, chef, knife

I have 5 nodes and all of them have one setup cook-book in common.

Now I would like to add another task in this common cookbook that would configure SQL server for me on all the nodes. Is there a way/command to manually trigger this change across all clients right away?

I use azure VM's. All the nodes are Windows Server 2012 machines. I could do a

```
knife winrm machine-name chef-client -m -x username -P password
```

on all the machines, but i'm sure there should be a better way of doing this. I'm new to using chef, so I might be missing a very basic command here.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using open-source Chef, the way you described is the easiest way to do it.

If you're using Enterprise Chef, [Push Jobs](https://docs.chef.io/push_jobs.html) is the feature you're looking for.